# Internet Connectivity problem but wi-fi is ok?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, connection, internet-connection

I am using windows-XP. I have a wi-fi internet connection. My system shows the wi-fi status ok. But still I am not able to browse the internet from my Pc(laptop).

I am sure this is not the browser settings problem.

But what it is I am not able to identify......

Please help me about the possible solution or the diagonosis steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset/Repair the TCP/IP stack.

To open a command prompt, click Start and then click Run. Type **cmd** in the Open box and then press **ENTER**

At the command prompt, type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
```

then type the following command and then press ENTER:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Reboot the computer.

*Note: if you're using static TCP/IP settings you will have to enter your settings again as this will reset the TCP/IP settings to Windows default (automatically obtained).*

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi icon shows your computer's connection to the *network*, not to the internet.

If you have a wireless adapter attached to a modem, try resetting the modem, or checking the router or modem's settings.

Comment: The wifi connection is at college level and internet works on every body elses computer. There is no way to reset the modem. All i can do is to check my computer settings.

Comment: If the other tips listed here don't work, you can always try giving your IT help desk (if you have one)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a DNS issue or a malware probem - both of which could cause this problem. Open a command prompt and type in "ipconfig \flushdns" without the quotes and then try to browse the Internet.

If that does not work, get a hold of a program called WinSockFix and run it to repair your network connections.